# Cache part of experiment in AzureML same as SPSS modeler?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, spss-modeler

I want to cache part of the stream executed successfully (marked as tick) in Azure ML so that next time run will start from the same point onwards.
Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Azure ML already does this.  When you run it the second time, if nothing upstream from that tick has changed it should just load the results from the previous run.  It may take a few seconds for Azure ML to recognize that it is cached and reload it.